# Spring Cloud microservice, consume password protected micro service with other micro service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

currently I'm following some tutorials to create micro services in java with spring and the neflix stack.
One problem I have is that every service I start seems to be protected by a generated password. So it is not possible for another microservice to use another one because of this. 
So what is the best and common way for one micro service to consume another via a rest call? Do I have to ajust the application.yml further and how?

Here is an example (very rough and basic). I have a micro service that calls another one with the following function:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookstoreApplication {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/recommended")
    public String readingList(){
        return "Spring in Action (Manning), Cloud Native Java (O'Reilly),    Learning Spring Boot (Packt)";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "springTut2CircuitBreakers/circuitApplication");
        SpringApplication.run(BookstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The other micro service is listening to that call with following code:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReadingApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/to-read")
    public String readingList() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended");

        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "springTut2CircuitBreakers/readingApplication");
        SpringApplication.run(ReadingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I try to use the first service with a browser I'm asked to enter a password. When I enter that I have acces to it but it shows me an 401 error becaus the first service could not acces the second (I belive). So how do I prevent that from happening?

Edit: Fixed Copy paste error(duplicated code)

Answer (score 0):

I think when security is enabled in both services, you need to send the session Id in the header of the rest template call like below,

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getValue());
HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
ResponseEntity rssResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
    "http://localhost:8090/recommended",
    HttpMethod.GET,
    requestEntity,
    Rss.class);
Rss rss = rssResponse.getBody();`
```

This may help in making rest template calls between your microservices (This rest template call to be changed accordingly).